# How to choose template in DetailView based on a field of the model shown?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model with a choice field:

```
type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
                            max_length=1, default=UNSET, db_index=True)
```

Depending on the type I'd like to show a different template in the class based DetailView:

```
class AlbumDetailView(DetailView):
[...]
```

Currently I have set the template by setting:

```
 template_name = 'bilddatenbank/album_detail.html'
```

But then it's not possible to access the value of the model field. Where can I can set the template while having access to the model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `get_template_names` method, so:

```
class AlbumDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'bilddatenbank/album_detail.html'

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.object.type == 't':  # special type
            return ('bilddatenbank/other_template.html',)
        return super().get_template_names()
```